# How can i check if an ObjectContext is still being used by the application?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, garbage-collection, object-reference

Well, the question pretty much says it all, but i'll try to give you the context. I'm using Entity Framework 4.0 where i frequently use the following syntax -

```
using (MLEntities context = ModelAccess.GetContext())
{
    /*just a sample statement*/
    this.ClientList = context.Clients.ToList();
    ...
    //Some other code
}
```

My understanding is that whenever i exit the `using` block, the `Dispose()` method of the `ObjectContext` class (base class of MLEntities) is called, which i guess releases any unmanaged resources, specifically in this case, the database connection. But since i'm holding a reference to the context object through `this.ClientList = context.Clients.ToList();` the context doesn't get garbage-collected. Right?

Now for some instantiated context objects, while the application is running i need to know if they are still being held, being used by the application, or they've been released. I don't have any reference of the context outside the `using` block, but even if i had any, an attempt to use that reference would make the context object being used by the application. So how can i do it? Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT :** Actually i didn't mean to say that i'm holding a direct reference to the context object. Honest mistake. What i meant is, since `Clients` is a property of the context and through `this.ClientList` i'm holding a reference to `Clients`, as long as the current object that instantiating the context lives with `this.ClientList`,won't it keep the context object alive too?

Comment: You are not holding a reference to the context object but rather to the list.

Answer (score 2):

`using() {}` will always dispose the object being used. You don't hold refference to context via ClientList. It's simple reference to list. Even if you have refference to context after it's disposed you will get [ObjectDisposedException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.objectdisposedexception%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) exception when accesing to it.

When context is disposed ClientList will be detached from context so EF will not track changes  of this list more.

Comment: `using() {}` will always call the object's `Dsipose()` method, and whether the object is actually disposed (removed from memory) depends on if `GC.Collect()` is called inside the `Dsipose()` method, right? may be for `ObjectContext` class that is done, but what about any other custom object?